# How to test an EJB service class that invokes a REST call?

Tags: json, jersey, testng, resteasy, wildfly-8

I'm aware that some developer say it's not a unit test to invoke a method of an EJB which requests a web resource. However, please do not argue about that in this thread! I think it is worthwhile to do it.

my Test: testng class --> EJB method --> rest resource

Setup:

- Wildfly 8.1
- TestNG 6.8.8
- jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec, 1.0.1.Final

This is my testing class.

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.doe.webapp.model.general.geoinfo.GeoInfo;

public class GeoIPBeanTest {

    @DataProvider(name = "ipAdresses")
    public static Object[][] primeNumbers() {
        return new Object[][] { 
                { "127.0.0.1", true }, // localhost
                { "80.218.114.61", true } }; // real IP
    }   

    @Test(dataProvider = "ipAdresses")
    public void getGeoInfoByIp(String ipAddress, boolean isExpectedTrue) {
        GeoIPBean geoIpBean = new GeoIPBean();
        GeoInfo geoInfo = null;
        try {
            geoInfo = geoIpBean.getGeoInfoByIp(ipAddress);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Assert.fail(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is my class under test.

```
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation.Builder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.doe.webapp.model.general.geoinfo.GeoInfo;

@Singleton
public class GeoIPBean {

private static final String IPV4_PATTERN = "^(([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.){3}([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";

Map<String, GeoInfo> geoInfoCache = new HashMap<String, GeoInfo>();
// Service Description is here http://freegeoip.net/
static final String GEO_SERICE_URL = "http://freegeoip.net/";
static final String FORMAT = "json";

public GeoInfo getGeoInfoByIp(String ipAddress) {
    if(!isValidIp(ipAddress)){
        //TODO log invalid IP as warning
        return null;
    }

    GeoInfo geoInfo = geoInfoCache.get(ipAddress);
    if (geoInfo == null) {

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        // Invoke the service.
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target(GEO_SERICE_URL + FORMAT + "/"
                + ipAddress);
        //geoInfo 
        Builder builder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        geoInfo = builder.get(GeoInfo.class);
    }
    return geoInfo;
}

public static boolean isValidIp(String ipAddress) {
    if(ipAddress == null)
        return false;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(IPV4_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ipAddress);
    return matcher.matches();
}
}
```

This EJB works when I run it in the container. It does NOT work in a testNG case.

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
```

This line in the EJB returnS the error.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder
    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
    at com.doe.webapp.service.general.geoinfo.GeoIPBeanTest.getGeoInfoByIp(GeoIPBeanTest.java:25)
```

I first thought it is because I have annotated the wildfly library with scope provided ...

```
<!-- JBOSS JAX REST 2.0 FRAMEWORK -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- RS client library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

... but Wildfly is using RestEasy and not Jersey. Then I added ...

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
   <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
```

... but did NOT help neither.

Answer (score 0):

In `Wildfly`, they have been using `RESTEasy` as the default rest provider. It [states](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.1.Final/userguide/html_single/#d4e40),

> RESTEasy is bundled with JBoss/Wildfly and completely integrated as per the requirements of Java EE 6.

Therefore you have to remove `RESTEasy` dependencies defore you use `Jersey` with `Jboss/Wildfly`. Eventhough I haven't done that, there can be many resources which guides to do that. ([Check](https://developer.jboss.org/message/744530) [these](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-1304) [links](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/164300?tstart=0).)

Or else, as an alternative, you can use `RESTEasy` instead of `Jersey`.